# ROS Answers SE migration: tfMessage ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where is tfMessage defined? It is used in the transform_broadcaster.cpp file. I have found a file called tfMessage.h, but it defines tfMessage_, not tfMessage.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10522/tfmessage-ros/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-07-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-07-09**:
There is. See the tf tutorials (http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials) for how to best use tf.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-08**:
I had been planning on writing a subscriber node that would interpret the tf messages. If it is not a good idea to directly interact with the messages, is there an existing subscriber node?

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-07-07**:
You probably already knew this, but for posterity's sake: you probably don't ever want to touch tf messages directly; instead, use TransformBroadcasters and TransformSubscribers to interact with tf at a transform level, not a message level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS messages are defined in files with the extension *.msg. So, tfMessage.msg is the file for which you're looking. For your convenience:

http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/msg/tfMessage.html

---

Originally posted by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) with karma: 753 on 2011-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3